# Doctrine does not automatically load joined relation using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two Doctrine entity classes: `Vertriebsschiene` and `Filiale`:

```
/**
 * Vertriebsschiene
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vertriebsschiene", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(columns={"name"}, flags={"fulltext"})
 * }))
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CRMBundle\Repository\VertriebsschieneRepository")
 */
class Vertriebsschiene
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;



    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Filiale", mappedBy="vertriebsschiene", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $filialen;

    ...
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Filiale
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="filiale")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CRMBundle\Repository\FilialeRepository")
 */
class Filiale extends Lieferant
{
    /**
     * @var Vertriebsschiene
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CRMBundle\Entity\Vertriebsschiene", inversedBy="filialen", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $vertriebsschiene;

    ...
}
```

The `Vertriebsschine` objects have a non-uniqe name. Now I try to display a list of `Vertriebsschiene` objects with their `Filiale` objects.

My findAllQuery method looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return \Doctrine\ORM\Query
 */
public function findAllQuery(User $user){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->select('v as vertriebsschiene')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(f) as filial_num')
        ->leftJoin('v.filialen', 'f')
        ->groupBy('v.name');

    $this->restrictAccess($user, $qb);

    return $qb->getQuery();
}


/**
 * @param User $user
 * @param $qb
 */
protected function restrictAccess(User $user, QueryBuilder &$qb)
{
    if ($user->hasRole(RoleVoter::AUSSENDIENST)) {

        $qb ->leftJoin('f.vertreter', 'u')
            ->leftJoin('u.vertretungen', 'vx')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
                'f.vertreter = :userid',
                'f.vertreter IS NULL',
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    'vx.proxy = :userid',
                    $qb->expr()->between(':currentDate', 'vx.start', 'vx.end')
                )
            ))
            ->setParameter('userid', $user->getId())
            ->setParameter('currentDate', new \DateTime(), \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the `Vertriebsschiene::$filiale` array collection is not automatically loaded, but is loaded for every `Vertriebsschiene` resulting in many DB connections.

This also has the problem, that the `WHERE` statement is ignored when the `Vertriebsschiene::$filiale` is fetched.

The `COUNT(f)` returns the correct amount of `Filiale` objects.

I suspect this is an issue with the `GROUP BY` statement.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you do not tell doctrine to select `filiale` fields.

Try to add the `filiale` alias in your select :

```
public function findAllQuery(User $user){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->select('v as vertriebsschiene', 'f')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(f) as filial_num')
        ->leftJoin('v.filialen', 'f')
        ->groupBy('v.name');

    $this->restrictAccess($user, $qb);

    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

If you check your query in the profiler, i think you'll see that doctrine add a `LEFT JOIN fialiale f0_ ON v0_.id = f0_.vertriebsschiene_id` (or something like this but does not add `SELECT ... f0_.id, f0_.xxxx`.

So every time you'll call `$vertriebsschiene->getFieliale()->getXXX()` doctrine will have to execute the corresponding query to get the filiale data.

Comment: No, this does not work. The problem is, as soon as I add the groupBy Clause, only one `filiale` gets selected.